# Generate serie with prefix and leading zeros (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, generate-series

I am trying to generate a serie that contains both prefix ('A') and leading zeros.

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(8,12)
```

will generate a serie

```
8
9
10
11
12
```

But I want to prefix and set max 4 leading zeros

```
A00008
A00009
A00010
A00011
A00012
```

Is this possible to do with a Postgresql query?

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 'A'||lpad(s::text,5,'0') as myval FROM generate_series(8,12) as t(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `to_char()` to format the number:

```
SELECT to_char(i, 'FMA00000') as x
FROM generate_series(8,12) as t(i)
```

For details on `to_char()` please [see the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)